# Drush missing the "provision" and "Hostmaster" commands

Tags: drush, aegir

One of our boxes is missing these Aegir-Drush commands (from `drush help`):

```
All commands in provision: (provision)
 backend-parse         Parse the output of --backend commands to a human readable form                                
 hostmaster-install    Install and verify the Hostmaster frontend.                                                    
 hostmaster-migrate    Migrate an instance of the Hostmaster front end to a new platform                              
 provision-backup      Generate a back up for the site.                                                               
 provision-backup_del  Delete a backup file.                                                                          
 ete                                                                                                                  
 provision-clone       Clone a site between platforms.                                                                
 provision-delete      Delete a site.                                                                                 
 provision-deploy      Deploy an existing backup to a new url.                                                        
 provision-disable     Disable a site.                                                                                
 provision-enable      Enable a disabled site.                                                                        
 provision-import      Turn an already running site into a provisioned site.                                          
 provision-install     Provision a new site using the provided data.                                                  
 provision-lock        Lock a platform from having any other sites provisioned on it.                                 
 provision-login_rese  Generate a one-time login reset URL.                                                           
 t                                                                                                                    
 provision-migrate     Migrate a site between platforms.                                                              
 provision-restore     Restore the site to a previous backup. This will also generate a backup of the site as it was. 
 provision-save        Save Drush alias                                                                               
 provision-unlock      Unlock a platform so that sites can be provisioned on it.                                      
 provision-verify      Verify that the provisioning framework is correctly installed.
```

We're able to log into Aegir via the web interface, but none of the commands work. The best we could tell, the install went fine. I think it might be related to these commands missing from our server.

How do I get these commands back? We were able to verify the Hostmaster platform with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have had similar issues with this in the past,

How many instances of drush is there on your server? In my case I had a drush 3.3 version in `/usr/share/drush` and the aegir 4.4 version (with provision and hostmaster commands) in `/var/aegir/.drush`

In order to get drush to work, I had to alter the path for the aegir user to include `/var/aegir/.drush` first

You can always tell which version of drush you are using by running the command

`which drush`

Comment: Haha, it was yet another "gotcha." Our setup has /home/aegir as the home directory, a RHEL quirk for keyless ssh to work, but all our files were in /var/aegir. Creating symlinks to the files in /var/aegir (including .drush -- we had missed this directory) in /home/aegir fixed this issue. Thanks again @wiifm.